# How to to reference an activity that implements an interface?

Tags: java, android

It says wrong third argument, I've implemented LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks in mainActivity.

```
getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID,getUrlBundle(),this);
```

Why is this happening ?

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MovieAdapter.movieAdapterClickHandler,LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Movie>> {
    ...
@Override

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...


   getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID,getUrlBundle(),this);
    }
    ...

@Override
    public Loader<List<Movie>> onCreateLoader(int i, final Bundle bundle) {
        return new AsyncTaskLoader<List<Movie>>(this) {
            @Override
            protected void onStartLoading() {
                if(bundle==null)
                    return;
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                errorMessage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                forceLoad();

            }

            @Override
            public List<Movie> loadInBackground() {
                /* Extract the url from the args using our constant */
                String UrlString = bundle.getString(URL_EXTRA);

                /* If the user didn't enter anything, there's nothing to search for */
                if (UrlString == null || TextUtils.isEmpty(UrlString)) {
                    return null;
                }

                return QueryUtils.fetchMovieData(UrlString);
            }

            @Override
            public void deliverResult(List<Movie> data) {
                super.deliverResult(data);
            }
        };



    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Movie>> loader, List<Movie> movies) {
        if (movies != null && !movies.isEmpty()) {
            movieAdapter.MovieAdapterUpdate(movies);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            errorMessage.setText("No data returned");
            errorMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<Movie>> loader) {

    }
    }
```

Comment: try `getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID,getUrlBundle(),MainActivity.this);`

Comment: It seems its because of the imports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if you're using the wrong imports for the Loader classes that you're using. For example, if you're using

```
import android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

along with

```
import android.app.LoaderManager;
```

then you'll get the wrong third argument warning as you're mixing support dependencies with non-support dependencies. Whereas this would work:

```
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Android Document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html)

```
initLoader(int id, Bundle args, LoaderCallbacks<D> callback)
```

You need to pass the loader callback